# Azure Stream Analytics: Calculate Slope from a Sliding Window

Tags: azure, bigdata, azure-stream-analytics, complex-event-processing, stream-analytics

**Data structure:** `{sensorId: 1, temp: 20, timestamp: 1525119377241}`

**Window Query**:

```
SELECT
    System.Timestamp as WindowEnd,
    sensorId,
    AVG(temp) AS avgTemp,
FROM
    SensorStream TIMESTAMP BY timestamp
GROUP BY
    sensorId,
    SlidingWindow(second, 30)
```

I would like to calculate in realtime the Slope between the actual avgTemp and the avgTemp 30s before.

Using a `tumbling window` would work by using `LAG(avgTemp, 1)` but this would only output every 30s.

**TL;DR:** I would like to calculate the slope in realtime everytime a new avgTemp is calculated by the sliding window.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [How to create a delayed sliding window in Azure Stream Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070169/how-to-create-a-delayed-sliding-window-in-azure-stream-analytics/50073591#50073591)

You can do it in two steps. Step 1 computes sliding window, Step 2 computes the slope using LAG.

Comment: That is exactly the issue: Using LAG on a SlidingWindow will give the previous emmited value, which can be less than 1s before and is not predictable because the events can come at any rate.

Calculating the slope between t and t-1s is not what I'm trying to do.
I'm trying to calculate between t and t-30s

Comment: So, is there a rate at which events are produced? what if there is no data at t -30s, but there is one at t-29 and another at t-31, which you want to be used?
you can use join instead of LAG and specify wiggle to be > 30s, but you also have to provide the upper bound, i.e "and <2min".